# Dynamically importing modules as global variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module

I am trying to dynamically import modules and get it as global variable.

I am using maya 2020 python interpreter (Python 2.7)

I have a test module called "trigger_test_script.py" under "/home/arda.kutlu/Downloads/" folder.

When I dont import any custom class and run this:

```
###########################################################################[START]
import sys
import imp

class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.filePath = None
        self.asName = None
    
    def action(self):
        exec("global %s" % self.asName, globals())
        foo = "imp.load_source('%s', '/home/arda.kutlu/Downloads/trigger_test_script.py')" %self.asName
        cmd = "{0}={1}".format(self.asName, foo)
        exec(cmd, globals())
###########################################################################[END]
        
test = TestClass()
test.filePath = "/home/arda.kutlu/Downloads/trigger_test_script.py"
test.asName = "supposed_to_be_global"
test.action()
print(supposed_to_be_global)
```

I get the exact result that I want:
`<module 'trigger_test_script' from '/home/arda.kutlu/Downloads/trigger_test_script.pyc'>`

However, when I save TestClass (the part between hashes) into a file and import it like this:

```
import testClass
test = testClass.TestClass()
test.filePath = "/home/arda.kutlu/Downloads/trigger_test_script.py"
test.asName = "supposed_to_be_global"
test.action()
print(supposed_to_be_global)
```

the variable which 'supposed_to_be_global' is not becoming global and I get the NameError.

I always assumed that these two usages should return the same result but clearly I am missing something.

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: The `exec` happens within the context of the module it was run from. You should not try to make your dynamic loader set the global variable dynamically, especially given that you have to tell it the name to use anyway. Just... get the module as the return value from `action`, and assign it yourself.

Comment: The problem is because the value returned by `globals()` is different when you put `TestClass` in a separate module — every module has it's own set of them.

Comment: I was fearing that. This action class module will be one of the several modules all have their own action method, producing different results. All actions getting driven by another controller class, which is also driven by the ui class. I will need a serious workaround for this one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your last comment about having several modules with different `action()` methods is a problem. So ignoring that, here's how to make what's in your question work, The part in the hashes will work both in-line or if put in a separate module and imported.

```
###########################################################################[START]
import imp

class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.filePath = None
        self.asName = None

    def action(self):
        foo = imp.load_source(self.asName, self.filePath)
        return foo
###########################################################################[END]

#from testclass import TestClass

test = TestClass()
test.filePath = "/home/arda.kutlu/Downloads/trigger_test_script.py"
test.asName = "supposed_to_be_global"
supposed_to_be_global = test.action()
print(supposed_to_be_global)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By multiple action methods i tried to say something like this. You may think this part as one of many action plugins connecting to another module. This will be the custom scripts module, where users can create their own scripts. There are other modules like importing geometries, building kinematics, replacing controller shapes etc. There may be arbitrary number of plugins. My problem is, I want to pass the imports to other custom script modules as well, which all will have individual contexts. User needs to define the 'supposed_to_be_global' value from ui.

Comment: I think you should use dictionaries, not the global namespace to do what you want — there seems little to no need to pollute it with a plug-in's variables.

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate how dictionaries can be used in this case?

Comment: I meant that user scripts would need to reference things through dictionaries that contained them instead of them being global variables that somehow come into existence.

Comment: Yes something similar was my initial thought but that would mean to alter my whole structure just for this single module. Guess I need to do that regardless. I am aware that global variables frowned upon just like exec() but for this case I thought I could have made use of it.